# Vue JS and Datatable No data available

Tags: vue.js, datatables

I am learning Vue JS and I am getting data from the backend using Axios to show it in data table. When I get the data and do a v-for I get **No data available in table** Below is my code.

Picture
[image]

Template

```
    <tbody >
        <tr v-for="user in users" v-bind:key="user">
            <td>{{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{user.username}}</td>
            <td>{{user.role}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            <td>{{user.is_active}}</td>
            <td>View</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

And script

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    name : "SystemAdmin",
    data(){
        return{
            users: []
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.checkUser()
    },
    methods:{
      async checkUser(){
        try {
            console.log('System Users')
            const response = await axios.get('superadmin/system-admins/');
            this.users = response.data.results
            console.log(response.data.results)
        } catch (err) {
          
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: there will be either a race condition on datatables seeing the dom and it being there or not seeing the virtual dom at all, using `this.$nextTick(this.checkUser)` in mounted then instead of using a model and v-for pass the rows to datatables [add](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) method.. don't use it myself its bloated and it fairly easy to implement ajax, column sorting, filtering and pagination in vue

Comment: Also, not the source of this issue, but you'll run into updating issues if you don't give each element a unique `:key`, since `user` is an object, the key is equal to `[object Object]`. You should update it to be `:key="user.id"` (or some similar unique attribute).

Comment: I tried these but nothing is changing. still showing no data available.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but the first mistake you could do is that when you are using DataTables you should not use the  because to show the data you only have to use **v-bind:data="arrayName"**

For example: Here is my example code where I needed to show all data in statistics.

```
<DataTable :options="options" width="100%" :columns="columns" :data="getData" class="aside-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="aside-column">ID</th>
                            <th class="aside-column">NAME</th>
                            <th class="aside-column">MUSIC</th>
                            <th class="aside-column">TOTAL VIEWS</th>
                            <th class="aside-column uppercase">from swipe
                            </th>
                            <th class="aside-column">FROM TRENDS</th>
                            <th class="aside-column">FROM CATEGORY</th>
                            <th class="aside-column">VIDEO START</th>
                            <th class="aside-column">COMPILE BTN CLICK</th>
                            <th class="aside-column">COMPILE</th>
                            <th class="aside-column uppercase">save camera roll</th>
                            <th class="aside-column uppercase">show subs on save
                            </th>
                            <th class="aside-column uppercase">subscription</th>
                            <th class="aside-column">LIKES</th>
                            <th class="aside-column">SHARES</th>
                            <th class="aside-column">VIDEO CANCELLED</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </DataTable>
```

Here is the function with Fetch API:

```
const items = []
```

const dataItems = async () => {
const options = {
method: 'GET',
headers: {
Authorization: `Bearer ${myToken}`,
'Content-Language': 'en',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
}

```
const all = {
    id: 0,
    template_name: "All",
    music_title: "All",
    views_count: 0,
    transitions_from_trends: 0,
    transitions_from_category: 0,
    compile_count: 0,
    compile_btn_click_count: 0,
    video_start_count: 0,
    video_cancelled_count: 0,
    like_count: 0,
    share_count: 0,
    transitions_from_swipe: 0,
    save_camera_roll_count: 0,
    show_subs_on_save_count: 0,
    subscription_count: 0
}

await apiDataFetch(`/admin/statistics/template?type=${type}`, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        let array = response.data
        array.forEach(item => {
            all.views_count += item.views_count
            all.transitions_from_trends += item.transitions_from_trends
            all.transitions_from_category += item.transitions_from_category
            all.compile_count += item.compile_count
            all.compile_btn_click_count += item.compile_btn_click_count
            all.video_start_count += item.video_start_count
            all.video_cancelled_count += item.video_cancelled_count
            all.like_count += item.like_count
            all.share_count += item.share_count
            all.transitions_from_swipe += item.transitions_from_swipe
            all.save_camera_roll_count += item.save_camera_roll_count
            all.show_subs_on_save_count += item.show_subs_on_save_count
            all.subscription_count += item.subscription_count

            items.push(item)
        })

        items.unshift(all)
    })

console.log(items)
```

}